# How to Install PostgreSQL 8.4 on 8.04?

Tags: installation, 8.04, postgresql

How can I install Postgresql 8.4 for Ubuntu Hardy 8.04 ?

`sudo apt-get install postgresql` will install postgreSQL 8.3

I tried installing individual packages from

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/hardy/main/backports/postgresql-8.4

but not able to resolve dependancies

Then tried to add

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-backports main
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main restricted universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted universe
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Running `sudo apt-get update` showed

```
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then the command `sudo apt-get install postgresql-8.4`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
postgresql-8.4 is already the newest version.
You might want to run âapt-get -f installâ to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
  libpq-dev: Depends: libpq5 (= 8.3.9-0ubuntu8.04) but 8.4.6-1~hardy1 is to be installed
  postgresql-8.4: Depends: postgresql-common (>= 109~) but it is not going to be installed
  postgresql-client-8.4: Depends: postgresql-client-common (>= 104~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try âapt-get -f installâ with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the German mirror you're using did not deliver. You could retry, or if the problem persists, try another mirror (change from `de.archive.ubuntu.com` to, say, `uk.archive.ubuntu.com`).

Comment: Tried, but got the same error message

Comment: I tried it also now and it worked perfectly (uk mirror). Could you retry? In case the problem persists, could you check that there are no problems with your file system: Is it full? Mounted with errors? Problems reported in the system log / dmesg? Or, could there be a proxy between you and the mirror that would give you stale files? In those cases, I'd try `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/??.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_hardy-updates*` even though it is unlikely to help, it also should not break anything. Just do a `apt-get update` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Hash Sum mismatch' message is important - try a different server instead of the de one (which is, I guess, located in Germany). Try adding the UK servers instead:

```
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-backports main
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-updates main restricted universe
deb http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main restricted universe
```

Then `sudo apt-get update && apt-get install postgresql-8.4`

Comment: Tried, but got the same error message